# C Programming: Print "Hello", "Red", "Green", "Blue" for different numbers in sequence from 0 to 24

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement, printf

My brain has just hit a wall and I'm not sure how to do this without going into an infinite loop and I mean both my brain and the code! No idea if I have over complicated it to the max or if I am on the right track. Any help would be much appreciated!

**The problem:**

I want to print a list of numbers similar to a Fizz Buzz sequence but instead they say "Hello", "Red", "Green" and "Blue" from 0 to 24. I want to use a for loop but I am stuck on how to add the logic for every occurrence.

For even numbers I want it to print "Hello" and I have already worked that out using modulo.

Now, I want Red, Green and Blue to start at different places but obey the same equation of:
"x + 6" at their respective starting points 1, 3 and 5.

I'm not sure how I can assign the values within the array(s) to the "i" variable of the for loop

**Objectives:**

Be able to print "Hello" for every even number.

Be able to print "Red" at  = {1, 7, 13, 19}.

Be able to print "Green" at = {3, 9, 15, 21}.

Be able to print "Blue" at = {5,11,17,23}.

**My code in C:**

```
int main ()
{
    int i,j,k,m;

    int R[] = {1,7,13,19}; 
    int G[] = {3,9,15,21}; 
    int B[] = {5,11,17,23};

    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        /* Even Numbers */
        if (i % 2)
        {
            printf("Hello\n", i);
        }
        /* Odd Numbers */
        if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                /* Red */
                if (i = R[j]) 
                    printf("Red\n", i);
            }
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                /* Green */
                if (i = G[k]) 
                    printf("Green\n", i);
            }
            for (m = 0; m < 4; m++)
            {
                /* Blue */
                if (i = B[m]) 
                    printf("Blue\n", i);
            }
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
0 Hello

1 Red

2 Hello

3 Green

4 Hello

5 Blue

6 Hello
```

Comment: Most striking, without deep analysis, is `if (i = B[m])`. Try `==`.

Comment: You can also do red green blue with `%`. Look at the values modulo 6, you should notice a simple pattern.

Comment: I fixed markdown and indentation of your code. But please upgrade to a clean [mre].

Comment: `printf("Hello\n", i);` Format descriptor %d is missing: `printf("%d Hello\n", i);`

Comment: Sorry, indeed I more broke than fixed markdown... but now. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch okay thank you, so I don't need the arrays or the for loops?

Comment: That is what I mean yes.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I disagree with tagging a question with a construct which you use in your answer, but not necessarily so. The question is not about switch statements.

Comment: @Yunnosch But logically it is a switch statement.

Comment: No it isn't. Or it would equally logically be a nested ternary operator or a lookup table. Tags are for characterising the question, not one possible answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch If there are used constants like 0, 1, 3, 5 then the code can be written using either the switch statement of if-else statements or as the conditional operator. But the last two are used when expressions are not constants. So logically there is more appropriate is the switch statement. As an assignment for beginners it should be based on the switch statement.

Comment: The assignment which the question is based on does not require constants. It is more about the 6-pattern. The constants appear in the definition of the objectives and OPs straight forward implementation.

Comment: LeonidasEng, I do not want to edit your question for adapting your tags to my opinion. May I ask you to decide whether you feel that your question is characterised by "switch statement"? Is that what you were asking about? Do you want to focus on answers which use a switch statment? Please [edit] according to your opinion.

Comment: @Yunnosch you're both right. To be honest, I am happy with many different answers and ways of doing things. This way I will learn better.

Comment: That seem to me like you do not want to characterise your question as being switch-statement related and want it to be more open for any solution approach. For that it would be appropriate to remove the tag or tags which unnecessarily restrict/focus the scope of your question. (Concerning that, Vlad and I cannot both be right....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you need something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { Red = 1, Green = 3, Blue = 5 };

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 24; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 )
        {
            printf( "%u %s\n", i, "Hello" );
        }
        else
        {
            switch( i % 6 )
            {
            case Red:
                printf( "%u %s\n", i, "Red" );
                break;

            case Green:
                printf( "%u %s\n", i, "Green" );
                break; 

            case Blue:
                printf( "%u %s\n", i, "Blue" );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 Hello
1 Red
2 Hello
3 Green
4 Hello
5 Blue
6 Hello
7 Red
8 Hello
9 Green
10 Hello
11 Blue
12 Hello
13 Red
14 Hello
15 Green
16 Hello
17 Blue
18 Hello
19 Red
20 Hello
21 Green
22 Hello
23 Blue
```

Or if you want to insert a blank line between two sequential outputs then just add one more new line character '\n' in the format string of the calls of printf like for example

```
printf( "%u %s\n\n", i, "Hello" );
              ^^^^^
```

Another approach is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    const char * color[] = { "Hello", "Red", "Green", "Blue" };

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 24; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 )
        {
            printf( "%u %s\n", i, color[0] );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%u %s\n", i, color[i % 6 / 2 + 1] );
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

Comment: @Yunnosh no sorry that was just the first part I did want it all the way up to 23.

Comment: Thank you so much @Vlad you guys are so fast you worked it out faster than I can type a reply! I just started coding and I'm sooo slow, but one day hopefully I will be quicker!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is what you wanted

```c
#include <stdio.h>
            
int main() {
    int i=1;
    int j=3;
    int k=5;

    for(int m=0;m<24;m++){
        if(m%2==0){
            printf("%d hello\n",m);
        }
        if(m==i){
            printf("%dred\n",m);
            i=i+6;
        }

        if(m==j){
            printf("%dgreen\n",m);
            j=j+6;
        }
            
        if(m==k){
            printf("%dblue\n",m);
            k=k+6;
        }           
    }
       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a simple and easy approach,  only one for loop , and checking at each breakpoint what to print (hello, red ,green or blue), giving a inital value to i ,j , k  and incrementing them by 6 at each condition ,to print at desired location

Comment: You can [edit] for adding the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as short and simple as I can make it.
Its a simple loop from 0 to 23 (inclusive), and a single `printf` statement, where the 3rd parameter to `printf` is just a chained ternary that checks for your various Red/Green/Blue/Hello situations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for(int i=0; i<24; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, i%6==1? "Red"  :
                             i%6==3? "Green":
                             i%6==5? "Blue" : "Hello");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5516KB
0 Hello
1 Red
2 Hello
3 Green
4 Hello
5 Blue
6 Hello
7 Red
8 Hello
9 Green
10 Hello
11 Blue
12 Hello
13 Red
14 Hello
15 Green
16 Hello
17 Blue
18 Hello
19 Red
20 Hello
21 Green
22 Hello
23 Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider the following solution too "fancy" for this.
I just add it to help completing the overview of possible different solutions.
This is with a lookup table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char* colors[]= {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
    for (int i=0;i<24;i++)
    {
        if(i%2)
        {    printf("%d %s\n\n", i, colors[(i/2)%3]);
            /* more obvious but less safe would be (i%6)/2 */
        } else
        {    printf("%d Hello\n\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```